# How do I make a conditional prompt that will continue to prompt until condition is met

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn javascript and have been playing around with a rock, paper, scissors game I made. Currently the user can enter anything in the prompt so I was trying to make a condition in which the prompt would continue to pop up if the user puts anything other than rock, paper or scissors. I have tried using while, do while and other attempts using if statements and have not been able to get it to work. Can anyone show me who I can make the prompt continue to pop up until the user puts the correct string? I didn't add the code since this is such a simple thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annoying code :

```
var test = 0;

while(test != 10) {
    test = parseInt(prompt('Enter ten'), 10);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mz97u/)